# Require Two of Four Properties

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

Assuming you have an interface like

```
interface Foo {
    a?: number[];
    b?: number[];
    c?: number[];
    d?: number[];
}
```

Is it possible to declare a type that would accept any combination of two properties (e.g., `a` and `b` or `a` and `c`) but would reject three properties (e.g., `a`, `b`, `c`)?

[I've made a TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Bar%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20b%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20c%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20a%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20d%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20Bar)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(a)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(%7B%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Afoo(%7B%20a%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%20b%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A) that I believe illustrates what I am expecting.

```
type Bar =
    { a: number[]; b: number[]; } |
    { a: number[]; c: number[]; } |
    { a: number[]; d: number[]; };       

function foo(a: Bar): void {
    console.log(a);
}

foo({ a: [1, 2], d: [1, 2] });
foo({ a: [1, 2], b: [1, 2], d: [1, 2] }); // Expected failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two conditional types to iterate over the keys twice and get a union of all possible combinations of two keys. The solution does not unfortunately scale to an arbitrary amount of keys (type aliasse can't easily be recursive) but you can create similar types for a specific number of combinations.

```
interface Foo {
    a?: number[];
    b?: number[];
    c?: number[];
    d?: number[];
}

type RequireTwoHelper<T, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T> =
    K2 extends string ? { [P in K1 | K2]-?:T[P] } : never;

type RequireTwo<T, K1 extends keyof T> =
    K1 extends string ? RequireTwoHelper<T, K1, Exclude<keyof T, K1>> : never;

type RequireTwoFoo = RequireTwo<Foo, keyof Foo>

let foo: RequireTwoFoo= { a:[], b:[] };
let foo2: RequireTwoFoo= { a:[], c:[] }
let foo3: RequireTwoFoo = { a: [], d: [] }
let foo4: RequireTwoFoo = { b: [], c: [] }
let foo5: RequireTwoFoo = { b: [], d: [] }
let foo6: RequireTwoFoo = { c: [], d: [] }

let foo7: RequireTwoFoo = { a[], c: [], d: [] } //err
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RequireTwoHelper%3CT%2C%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20K2%20extends%20string%20%3F%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20K1%20%7C%20K2%5D-%3F%3AT%5BP%5D%20%7D%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RequireTwo%3CT%2C%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20K1%20extends%20string%20%3F%20RequireTwoHelper%3CT%2C%20K1%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K1%3E%3E%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20RequireTwo%3CFoo%2C%20keyof%20Foo%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%5B%5D%2C%20b%3A%5B%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Alet%20foo2%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%5B%5D%2C%20c%3A%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20foo3%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20foo4%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20c%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20foo5%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0Alet%20foo6%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20%7B%20c%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20foo7%3A%20RequireTwoFoo%20%3D%20%7B%20a%5B%5D%2C%20c%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20d%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%20%2F%2Ferr%0D%0A)